# How does sklearn.preprocessing.normalize normalize data, and can I replicate on new data with mean and standard deviation?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I was working on a data science problem, and I used sklearn's preprocessing normalize function to normalize my dataset. Now, once I saved my model, I want to know how to apply those transformations to a new data point so I can feed it into the model and get a prediction.

What I have saved is

```
finalmodel.pkl
finalmodel.sav
statistics.csv
```

The statistics sheet has the mean and standard deviation from each column. Is the normalization the usual dividing by standard deviation after subtraction from mean, or does sklearn employ some other strategies?

Comment: The default normalization is the L2, or [Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm), norm.

Comment: You can save (pickle) your fitted normalizer object and use it to `transform()` the new data, which will preserve the fit from the training data. Note, this is a great use case for a `pipeline` which can be fitted and saved with all steps all at once

Comment: No, I don't think it can. But the `normalization` only divides by a single scalar value, so that should be easy enough to store somehow?

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks! You should answer so I can approve it :)

Comment: @ALollz is correct, in that there is a difference between sklearn's [normalize](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) function, and the equivalent [Normalizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer) object. For my suggestion to work, you would need to use the `Normalizer` to use `fit` and `transform` from the sklearn "estimator API"

Comment: @G.Anderson so if I understand correctly, I need to use the Normalizer object from the sklearn.preprocessing module and fit it, then use it to transform my dataset, then do the training with my normalized dataset, and save the fitted Normalizer, and then when I want to make a prediction, I load the normalizer and transform my point before I make a prediction, correct?

Comment: That should work exactly as you describe, yes!

Answer (score 1):

Independently of what normalization system you use, [sklearn.preprocessing.normalize](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) also provides the argument ***return_norm***, which you can set to True and store the norms used for later use.

Here's an example, using L2 (a.k.a. [Taxicab distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[3, 4], [5, 6]])
values, norms = normalize(x, norm='l1', return_norm=True)
```

you will now notice that:

```
values

Out[18]: array([[0.42857143, 0.57142857],
               [0.45454545, 0.54545455]])

norms

Out[19]: array([ 7., 11.])
```

Now, just as a check, divide one array item by the corresponding column norm:

```
3/7

Out[20]:  0.42857142857142855
```

Comment: How about L2 normalizing? How is it computed?